# python3.7 is not able to open jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have two versions of python in my Macbook, python3.7 and python3.8. I've been using python3.7 to do my data analysis. I used $python3.7 -m jupyter notebook to open jupyter notebook all the time. I've stopped for a while, last week I typed the same command in the terminal, jupyter notebook was opened by python3.8. I tried different ways, seems python3.7 isn't functional at all, jupyter notebook is only able to be opened by python3.8.

I have two questions:

1. How to open jupyter notebook again with python3.7?
2. Can I use python3.8 to keep analyzing the data generated in python 3.7? I tried to do some analysis in python3.8, seems it's fine so far, but I'm not sure about it as I'm still a beginner.

Thank you in advance for your nice help!

Yi

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of python3.7 it had known issues. I do not know why your jupyter-notebook stopped working suddenly but you can use python3.8. I doubt that you are using any processes that got deprecated between the two major releases.

Comment: Hi Hussam, thanks for your reply! As long I can use a different version to do my analysis, I don't mind getting rid of 3.7. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting up a virtual environment with whatever python version you want:

```sh
$ virtualenv --python=python3.7 env/
$ source env/bin/activate
(env) $ pip install ...
```

This approach avoid any dependencies clashing and isolate you project dependencies from the system ones.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the suggestion, it still opens jupyter notebook with pytho3.8, I don't understand why python3.7 opened jupyter notebook with 3.8. I'll probably just get rid of 3.7 and keep using 3.8. Thanks!